# How to better get distinct rows in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

My query gets all the information I need, but for the life of me, I can't seem to get it to organize the rows the way I want.  The information comes from 2 different table, obviously, and one is organized so the the day I want isn't organized in an easy-to-get fashion, like this:

```
post_id | meta_key | meta_value
--------|----------|-----------
1       | key_one  | value1
1       | key_two  | value2
2       | key_one  | value3
2       | key_two  | value4
```

When I want:

```
post_id | key_one | key_two
--------|----------|-----------
1       | value1   | value2
2       | value3   | value4
```

This is the query, and the return is below that.  Again, right information, but scattered throughout rows.  I know I'm just a statement away...

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'allowed' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END allowed,
CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'amenities' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END amenities,
CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'trail-type' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END trailtype,
CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'weatherlat' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END weatherlat,
CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'weatherlon' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END weatherlon
from wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id IN (SELECT object_id AS id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 74)
```

Here's the response, and below that, what I'm trying to get

```
post_id | allowed | amenities | trailtype | weatherlat | weatherlon
--------|---------|-----------|-----------|------------|-----------
503     | 1,2,3   | NULL      | NULL      | NULL       | NULL
503     | NULL    | No-Water  | NULL      | NULL       | NULL
503     | NULL    | NULL      | Easy      | NULL       | NULL
503     | NULL    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL       | NULL
503     | NULL    | NULL      | NULL      | 47.37070   | NULL
503     | NULL    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL       | -122.00633
566     | 5,6,7   | NULL      | NULL      | NULL       | NULL
566     | NULL    | Restrooms | NULL      | NULL       | NULL
566     | NULL    | NULL      | Moderate  | NULL       | NULL
566     | NULL    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL       | NULL
566     | NULL    | NULL      | NULL      | 47.729212  | NULL
566     | NULL    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL       | -117.142829
```

And what I want

```
post_id | allowed | amenities | trailtype | weatherlat | weatherlon
--------|---------|-----------|-----------|------------|-----------
503     | 1,2,3   | No-Water  | Easy      | 47.37070   | -122.00633
566     | 5,6,7   | Restrooms | Moderate  | 47.729212  | -117.142829
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your query to use `group by` and an aggregation function on each column:

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, 
       max(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'allowed' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END) as allowed,
       max(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'amenities' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END) as amenities,
       max(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'trail-type' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END) as trailtype,
       max(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'weatherlat' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END) as weatherlat,
       max(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'weatherlon' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END) as weatherlon
from wp_postmeta
where wp_postmeta.post_id IN (SELECT object_id AS id
                              FROM wp_term_relationships
                              WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 74
                             )
group by wp_postmeta.post_id;
```